# How to deal with anonymous login attempts when you allow both anonymous access and logged in users?

Tags: scala, authentication, challenge-response, www-authenticate

I have a framework that allows anonymous access as well as named user accounts. I'm exposing an OData resource on a certain URL. When configured as such, anonymous users can see parts of the resource and logged in users (through basic authentication) can see more.

The problem I'm facing is that some OData clients (like Excel) will initially attempt to access the OData resource anonymously even when you do provide credentials. Only when this fails, they will use the provided credentials. My understanding is that this is because there are many ways to log in and some clients just always try the most basic option first. But this prevents them from ever actually seeing more data, because they never use the provided credentials and also never get the authentication challenge when the resource allows anonymous access.

Is there a way to solve this issue, allowing both anonymous access AND properly sending an authentication challenge when possible? Is there maybe some header that clients will send when they do have credentials but just aren't supplying them initially?

Some (scala) code to make this a bit more tangible:

```
  val (username, password) = getAuthInfo(request)
  if (username != null && password != null) {
    val regularSession = integration.core.login(username, password)
    logger.debug(s"Login OK: User '$username' (Number of concurrent sessions: ${integration.core.getNumberConcurrentSessions}).")
    (IMxRuntimeResponse.OK, null, regularSession)
  } else if (integration.configuration.getEnableGuestLogin) {
    val guestSession = integration.core.initializeGuestSession
    logger.debug(s"Anonymous user '${guestSession.getUser.getName}' created " +
      "(Number of concurrent sessions: ${integration.core.getNumberConcurrentSessions}).")
    (IMxRuntimeResponse.OK, null, guestSession)
  } else {
    val responseMessage = "No basic authentication in header."
    logger.warn(s"Login failed: $responseMessage")
    (IMxRuntimeResponse.UNAUTHORIZED, responseMessage, null)
  }
```

Somewhere else outside the surrounding try/catch:

```
if (httpStatusCode == IMxRuntimeResponse.UNAUTHORIZED)
      response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic")
```

As you can see the challenge is never sent when anonymous access is allowed.

**Edit: we investigated and there does not seem to be anything special in the headers of this request that would indicate this is an initial attempt that will result in another request when an authentication challenge is sent, rather than just another anonymous login attempt. We are at a loss here now on how to proceed.**